# Am I thinking in React, with this set of components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building an dummy App to try learn React. What I have is a small tool bar with some buttons which should launch different modals. I want to know if I am thinking in React correctly before I take the wrong approach.

So, I have components:

`App
  <Toolbar />
     <Button />
  <Modal />`

This is simplified, but you can see that my `Toolbar` and `Modal` are siblings.

Is this a good way to do this, or should I have the modal coupled to its launching button? (The reason I chose to uncouple them is in case I came across a situation where something could be triggered by different events).

Also, if this way is fine, am I right in thinking that to pass state around (open modal for instance), the `Button` should pass the state up to the `App` and then back to the `Modal`?

I think communicating between components is the only part I am really not getting at the moment.

Comment: Button cannot pass 'state' up the Components i.e App , you have to use callback(available from App Component) to pass any data to upside Component (App) . And from there you can update your state .  For communicating from top to down Component use props and for communicating up the component use Callback

Answer (score 1):

You're OK with your set of components. Passing state with buttons is not a good idea though. Better approach is, you tie your state with modal itself and clicking buttons will execute a function(say 'action') that will change state of modal, causing it to re-render itself.
For more advanced stuff you'll need to couple react with libraries like Flux or Redux so that you delegate state management work to them.